# Deleting and recreating the same document in a batch update in Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

There may be a situation in my app where the exact same document could be deleted and also added in the same batch update. The document ID and data would be exactly the same. If it matters, the `deleteDocument` batch update operation is added first. My assumption would be that the document would remain exactly as before. Is this the correct assumption?

It may not matter, but I am using Xcode, ios, and swift.

Comment: You could test this pretty easily yourself, no?

Comment: I just tested it and achieved the desired result, thank you for the recommendation. Furthermore, the order of adding the batch operations is important. Looking like they will always execute in order of addition to the batch. A follow up question would be, is this always the case?

Comment: I see no reason why the SDK would choose an unpredictable order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operations in a batch update will occur sequentially in the order you add them. So for the described case, the document will appear unchanged at the end of the batch update. If the delete operation is added after the create/update operation, the document will be deleted. As Doug said, this is always the case.